# Cron Expression for a time range

Tags: java

I am unable to create cron expression to fire every 5 minutes starting at 3:45am and
ending at 7:20am every day.

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Jesper I am using cron expression in java only through package  org.quartz.CronExpression;
org.quartz.CronTrigger;

Answer (score 1):

try several triggers, this is too complicated for one. register all of them with the same job.

Answer (score 1):

Morsch,

Did you mean like this:

- 45/5 3 * * ?
- 0/5 4-7 * * ?
- 0-20 7 * * ?

Thanks,
Ashish Khandelwal